# i have a list of values mentioned in a column. i want to use vba to pick x number of values from that list

Tags: vba

I have a list of values mentioned in a column. i want to use vba to pick x number of values from that list.the number x is mentioned in another cell. can you help me?

i have tried various formulas but no solution.

Comment: Please explain better your problem and show what you have tried. Even if it did not work, at least it helps better understand the problem.

Comment: It is to pick random X number of values. X is mentioned as a cell value in some cell. Let  me explain again. A,B c d e f g h are 8 values mentioned in eight cells A1 to A7. In B1 it is written as x for eg: 2.  I want the macro to read the value in B1 then understand that it has to randomly pick any 2 values from a1 to a7 and show anywher in column c.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `myColumnRng` is your range of cells in a columns containing your list of values, you can get its first N elements in a Variant array as follows:

```
 myElements = Application.Transpose(myColumnRng .Resize(nElements).Value)
```

to give a little bit more of context:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myColumnRng As Range
    Dim myElements As Variant
    Dim iEl As Long

    Set myColumnRng = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| set your range as the column "A" one from row 1 down to last not empty row

    myElements = Application.Transpose(myColumnRng .Resize(nElements).Value)

    For iEl = 1 To UBound(myElements)
        Debug.Print myElements(iEl)
    Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: @DevBg, did you get through it?

Comment: It is to pick random X number of values. X is mentioned as a cell value in some cell. Let  me explain again. A,B c d e f g h are 8 values mentioned in eight cells A1 to A7. In B1 it is written as x for eg: 2.  I want the macro to read the value in B1 then understand that it has to randomly pick any 2 values from a1 to a7 and show anywher in column c.

Answer (score 0):

Pick x values on random, or pick first x values in the list?

Comment: It is to pick random X number of values. X is mentioned as a cell value in some cell.

Comment: It is to pick random X number of values. X is mentioned as a cell value in some cell. Let  me explain again. A,B c d e f g h are 8 values mentioned in eight cells A1 to A7. In B1 it is written as x for eg: 2.  I want the macro to read the value in B1 then understand that it has to randomly pick any 2 values from a1 to a7 and show anywher in column c.